# Multiple blockers and trample

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I just thought about the fact that you can deal as much damage to one creature when multiple blocked

So lets say I have an 8/8 with trample
I attack with it

Im blocked by a 1/1 a 2/2 and a 3/3
(Maybe they wanted to stop 6 of the 8 damage but don't have the creatures to kill my 8/8 or maybe they have a card to play or something, thats not really important but maybe thats why they multi blocked without enough to kill the 8/8)

Could I assign 8 damage to the 1/1 and 0 to the 2/2 and 3/3?
If so, would the trample damage go to the player?

Comment: Its not a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assign lethal combat damage to all blocking creatures before you can assign any to the player.  From the rules (emphasis mine):

> 702.19b The controller of an attacking creature with trample first assigns damage to the creature(s) blocking it. Once all those blocking
>   creatures are assigned lethal damage, any remaining damage is assigned
>   as its controller chooses among those blocking creatures and the
>   player or planeswalker the creature is attacking. When checking for
>   assigned lethal damage, take into account damage already marked on the
>   creature and damage from other creatures that’s being assigned during
>   the same combat damage step, but not any abilities or effects that
>   might change the amount of damage that’s actually dealt. **The attacking
>   creature’s controller need not assign lethal damage to all those
>   blocking creatures but in that case can’t assign any damage to the
>   player or planeswalker it’s attacking.**

Short answer: no, you can't assign 0 to the 2/2 and the 3/3 and still hit the defending player.  You have to assign enough damage to all the blockers to otherwise kill them before you can assign any leftover damage to the player.

Answer (score 4):

If you assign all 8 damage to the 1/1, then the trample creature deals 8 damage to the 1/1. It deals no damage to the player because you did not assign any damage to the player.

Damage is assigned during the [Combat Damage Step](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Combat_damage_step), and rule 510.1c describes how attacking creatures deal damage:

> A blocked creature assigns its combat damage to the creatures blocking it. If no creatures are currently blocking it (if, for example, they were destroyed or removed from combat), it assigns no combat damage. If exactly one creature is blocking it, it assigns all its combat damage to that creature. **If two or more creatures are blocking it, it assigns its combat damage to those creatures according to the damage assignment order announced for it. This may allow the blocked creature to divide its combat damage. However, it can’t assign combat damage to a creature that’s blocking it unless, when combat damage assignments are complete, each creature that precedes that blocking creature in its order is assigned lethal damage.** When checking for assigned lethal damage, take into account damage already marked on the creature and damage from other creatures that’s being assigned during the same combat damage step, but not any abilities or effects that might change the amount of damage that’s actually dealt. **An amount of damage that’s greater than a creature’s lethal damage may be assigned to it.**

That process is modified/extended by the rules for [Trample](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Trample). Rule 702.19b says

> ***The controller of an attacking creature with trample first assigns damage to the creature(s) blocking it.* Once all those blocking creatures are assigned lethal damage, any remaining damage is assigned as its controller chooses among those blocking creatures and the player or planeswalker the creature is attacking.** When checking for assigned lethal damage, take into account damage already marked on the creature and damage from other creatures that’s being assigned during the same combat damage step, but not any abilities or effects that might change the amount of damage that’s actually dealt. The attacking creature’s controller need not assign lethal damage to all those blocking creatures but in that case can’t assign any damage to the player or planeswalker it’s attacking.

Comment: But when you are single blocked all 8 automatically goes to the creature but would still hurt the player the ability trample says extra damage can be assigned to the player or planeswalker, to the 1/1 there would be 7 extra that could be assigned

Comment: @128Gigabytes That isn't how it works. You have to assign the damage to the player, if you choose to assign it all to the creature it will all be dealt to the creature.

Comment: But it would be unknown how much damage was "Extra" until combat is resolving because people could play titanic groth or something, otherwise could I not attack with a 8/8 be blocked by a 2/2 and assign 2 to the creature and 6 to the player, and they play titanic groth, then what happens does their creature still only get 2 and the player get 6?

Comment: @128Gigabytes Damage is assigned after you get your last chance to cast spells and activate abilities.

Comment: Re "But when you are single blocked all 8 automatically goes to the creature", No, it doesn't. you have to decide how much to assign to the creature, and how much to assign to the player.

Comment: Right, this is the fundamental misunderstanding. If you had a 50/10 trample and I was controlling you for your turn, I could attack with it, block with a 0/1 and a 10/5 and then assign all 50 damage to the 0/1 creature. The 0/1 and the 50/10 would die, and the 10/5 would be fine, and I as a player would take no damage.